# How does Scala's apply() method magic work?

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar, magic-methods, companion-object

In Scala, if I define a method called `apply` in a class or a top-level object, that method will be called whenever I append a pair a parentheses to an instance of that class, and put the appropriate arguments for `apply()` in between them. For example:

```
class Foo(x: Int) {
    def apply(y: Int) = {
        x*x + y*y
    }
}

val f = new Foo(3)
f(4)   // returns 25
```

So basically, `object(args)` is just syntactic sugar for `object.apply(args)`.

How does Scala do this conversion?

Is there a globally defined implicit conversion going on here, similar to the implicit type conversions in the Predef object (but different in kind)? Or is it some deeper magic? I ask because it seems like Scala strongly favors consistent application of a smaller set of rules, rather than many rules with many exceptions. This initially seems like an exception to me.

Comment: Very great explanation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/#9738862

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I don't think there's anything deeper going on than what you have originally said: it's just syntactic sugar whereby the compiler converts `f(a)` into `f.apply(a)` as a special syntax case.

This might seem like a specific rule, but only a few of these (for example, with `update`) allows for [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)-like constructs and libraries.

Comment: I'd add "when `f` is an object (including functions)". When `f` is a method, there is obviously no such translation.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Well, if `f` is a method that is defined without a parameter list, then `f(a)` is indeed interpreted as something like `val _tmp = f; _tmp.apply(a)`. But that's really getting firmly into the splitting-of-hairs territory.

Answer (score 20):

It is actually the other way around, an object or class with an apply method is the normal case and a function is way to construct implicitly an object of the same name with an apply method. Actually every function you define is an subobject of the Function*n* trait (n is the number of arguments).

Refer to section **6.6:Function Applications** of the [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications) for more information of the topic.

Comment: +1 for changing the Scala Language Specification.
I added the right location since your page number is outdated.

Answer (score 8):

> I ask because it seems like Scala strongly favors consistent application of a smaller set of rules, rather than many rules with many exceptions.

Yes. And this rule belongs to this smaller set.