# Can't understand Iteratee.fold in Play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, loops

I'm reading the source code of Iteratee.scala: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Iteratee.scala

Specifically the convenience method for constructing the "fold" iteratee.

```
def fold[E, A](state: A)(f: (A, E) => A): Iteratee[E, A] = {
  def step(s: A)(i: Input[E]): Iteratee[E, A] = i match {

    case Input.EOF => Done(s, Input.EOF)
    case Input.Empty => Cont[E, A](i => step(s)(i))
    case Input.El(e) => { val s1 = f(s, e); Cont[E, A](i => step(s1)(i)) }
  }
  (Cont[E, A](i => step(state)(i)))
}
```

On each of the case statements, we are calling **Done** or **Cont** constructors. But where are these constructors defined? I infer that these must be implementors of the **Iteratee** trait but I couldn't find them by doing ctrl+F for "extends Iteratee."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [docementation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Done$.html) or [source](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Iteratee.scala):

```
object Done {
/**
* Create an [[play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee]] in the “done” state.
* @param a Result
* @param e Remaining unused input
*/
  def apply[E, A](a: A, e: Input[E] = Input.Empty): Iteratee[E, A] = new Iteratee[E, A] {
    def fold[B](folder: Step[E, A] => Future[B]): Future[B] = folder(Step.Done(a, e))
  }
}
```

It's not a constructor. `Done(s, Input.EOF)` [means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738862/406435) `Done.apply(s, Input.EOF)`. Same with `Cont`.

Comment: Oh, it's a singleton method! Confusing that they're trying to disguise it as a class though. Thanks!

Comment: Call of constructor should starts with `new`.

Comment: @Mark: As a warning, these aren't _constructors_ in the Java sense, but they are in the ADT sense, and you'll often see references to e.g. "the `Done` constructor" that mean exactly what you see here.

Comment: @TravisBrown: Not in this case though, because Iteratee is not a composite of type. Right?

Answer (score -1):

`Done` doesn't need to directly extend `Iteratee`. It could extend another class or trait which then extends `Iteratee`. You could search for `class Cont` and then follow the inheritance relationship from there.