# Scala type compilation error

Tags: scala, syntax, type-alias

Try to understand how I can use type in scala:

```
object TypeSample extends App {

  type MyParams = Map[Int, String]

  def showParams(params: MyParams) = {
    params.foreach(x => x match { case (a, b) => println(a + " " + b) })
  }

  //val params = MyParams( 1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
  val params = Map( 1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")

  showParams(params)

}
```

This line throws compilation exception: "Can not resolve symbol 'MyParams'"

```
//val params = MyParams( 1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
```

Why? I can not use 'type' like this?

Comment: Also note that instead of `(x => x match { case (a, b) => ...` you can just write `{ case (a, b) => ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `MyParams` is only an alias to the type `Map[Int, String]`. To make this work, you have to add a factory like

```
object MyParams {
  def apply(params: (Int, String)*) = Map(params: _*)
}
```

Comment: I guess, it is the option to make the compiler/scala even more smarter if one make an alias to some Class, and this class has companion object with apply method in it, then alias could use this.. since alias = synonym

Answer (score 4):

`Map( 1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")` [means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738862/406435) `Map.apply( 1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")`. `Map` is a singleton object.

Try this:

```
val MyParams = Map.apply[Int, String] _
```