# Python and functional programming: is there an apply() function?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Scala has the   [`apply()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/what-is-the-apply-function-in-scala) function.

I am new to Python and I am wondering how should I write the following one-liner:

```
(part_a, part_b) = (lambda x: re.search(r"(\w+)_(\d+)", x).groups())(input_string)
```

I would feel better with something like:

```
(part_a, part_b) = input_string.apply(lambda x: re.search(r"(\w+)_(\d+)", x).groups())
```

Am I wrong from a FF viewpoint? Is there such construction in Python?

*Edit: I know about the poorly picked snippet.*

Comment: No, there isn't, but it would be easy enough to write your own such that `part_a, part_b = apply(lambda ...: ..., input_string)` worked.

Comment: That would require all objects to have an apply method, which they don't. So I'm afraid that you have to live with that.  Note that what you would feel better with is a longer way to write the same thing.

Comment: Python has had an `apply` function since the beginning too, but since `apply(fn, args, kwargs) == fn(*args, **kwargs)` there is little use for it anymore..

Comment: Maybe [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Comment: why are you doing a lambda function if you are going to use it just once? whats wrong with `re.search(r"(\w+)_(\d+)", input_string).groups()`?

Comment: My example snippet was poorly picked...

Comment: Guido managed to kill `apply` off for Python 3.

Comment: python is a procedural language. it has good support for higher order operations and some functional techniques, but basically it is, by design, a procedural language - Guido has been quite explicit about this. That said, there is a lot to make you feel at home - read the docs for the `itertools`, `functools` and `operator` modules. Oh and maybe choose a better example next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When writing Haskell write Haskell. When writing Python just write Python:

```
part_a, part_b = re.search(r"(\w+)_(\d+)", input_string).groups()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a Python without `apply`, you could always write it yourself...

```
def apply(fn, args=(), kwargs=None):
    if kwargs is None:
        kwargs = {}
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

just because you could, doesn't mean you should..

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have such a construct; what would be the point?  `lambda x: ...` is a function, and therefore it should be used like a normal function, i.e., as `(lambda x: ...)(input_string)` as in your first snippet.

However, in your case, I see no reason why you should even bother with a lambda; just do:

```
(part_a, part_b) = re.search(r"(\w+)_(\d+)", input_string).groups()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about re-use, you could compile the regex:

```
rx = re.compile(r"(\w+)_(\d+)")
a, b = rx.search(input_string).groups()
```

Comment: I tend to do it for documentation more than performance (assuming I can give `rx` an informative name).

Answer (score 1):

Python used to have a apply function ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply)), but it has been removed in python 3, since it was unnecessary and against python's principle that there should be only one way to do a particular thing.

Say, we have a function called "func", we can easily call func(*args) instead of apply(func, args).