# Scala SortedMap under the hood

Tags: scala

I use `SortedMap` for storing ordered elements:

```
val map = SortedMap("Kim" -> 90, "Steve" -> 22, "Alex" -> 12)
```

My questions are:

1. What is the implementation stand under `SortedMap`?
2. Does `SortedMap` same to `Red black tree`?
3. `SortedMap` in Java is an interface, why in Scala it can be instantiated?

Comment: 3. is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/what-is-the-apply-function-in-scala#9738862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default implantation of `SortedMap` in Scala is a [TreeMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/TreeMap.html) which is an [immutable Red-Black tree](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#redblack_trees). Not to be confused with Java's java.util.TreeMap which is mutable.

Why SortedMap in Scala can be instantiated? It can't, it's a trait but the SortedMap companion object gives you the flexibility to initialise the object this way.

Comment: Why `SortedMap` is related to `TreeMap`, this two concepts must be separate like class and trait?

Comment: @pacman They are separate, but TreeMap is the default implementation.

Comment: where is the place in scala code where `SortedMap` delegate to `TreeMap`?

Comment: @pacman https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/SortedMap.scala#L91