# Function Definition In Scala

Tags: scala

Can any one explain me how this two types of function Definition differ from each other. Its just a syntax? or things are bigger than I am thinking of...

Approach 1

```
def incriment(x:Int):Int  = x+1
```

Approach 2

```
def incriment=(x:Int) =>x+1
```

Comment: `val` can also be used to write a function definition as in `val incr: (Int=>Int) = (x:Int)=>x+1`  Note this syntax defines the parameter type(s) and return type up front, and then provides the code.

Answer (score 1):

scala REPL is your friend,

**first one,** is simply **a method that takes int as input** and **returns int** as return type.

```
scala> def increment1(x:Int): Int = x + 1
increment1: (x: Int)Int
             |       |
           input     return type
```

And method must be provided an input,

```
scala> increment1
<console>:12: error: missing arguments for method increment1;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       increment1

scala> increment1(89)
res3: Int = 90
```

**second one,** is **a method that returns a function** which take int and returns int

```
scala> def increment2 = (x:Int) => x + 1
increment2:              Int    =>  Int
                          |          |
                        func input   func return type

//you can pass this function around, 

scala> increment2
res5: Int => Int = <function1>
```

to invoke a function, you can call `apply` method.

```
scala> increment2.apply(89)
res7: Int = 90

// or you can simply pass parameter within paren, which will invoke `apply`

scala> increment2(89)
res4: Int = 90
```

**also read** [What is the apply function in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738862/432903)

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, we can skip return type if type inference is simple.

In first approach:

```
def increment(x: Int) : Int = x + 1
```

It is a function returning Integer (increment the integer argument)

But in Second approach:

```
def increment = (x:Int) =>x+1
```

This is actually a function which returns another function.
The returned function can be called by a client passing integer and getting incremented integer in response

Answer (score 0):

Those two functions are completely different.

Re. 1

```
def incriment(x: Int) : Int = x + 1
```

This is just a function that returns an `Int`.

Re. 2

```
def incriment = (x: Int) => x+1
def incriment : (Int) => Int = (x:Int) => x+1
```

This one is a function that returns a function which takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`  (`(Int) => Int`). I've added type annotations to make things clear. Scala allows you to omit this, but sometimes it's recommended to add it (ex. for public methods etc.).