# Understanding of Case class in Scala

Tags: scala

I have below code  but when i remove case statement , object instance(Donut) cannot able to refer . I want to understand with simple example with class and case class statements  , Please advise . Also i want to understand why '(' ')' is printed in my second print statement.

```
 case class Donut(name: String, tasteLevel: String)

   val favoriteDonut2: Donut = Donut("Glazed Donut", "Very Tasty")
   println(s"My favorite donut name = ${favoriteDonut2.name}, 
          tasteLevel =  ${favoriteDonut2.tasteLevel}")
   println( s"My fav donut name is = ${favoriteDonut2.name}",
            s"taste level is       = ${favoriteDonut2.tasteLevel}")

output:-
   My favorite donut name = Glazed Donut, tasteLevel = Very Tasty
   (My fav donut name is = Glazed Donut,taste level is     = Very Tasty)
```

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/what-is-the-apply-function-in-scala

Answer (score 3):

When you call `Donut("Glazed Donut", "Very Tasty")` you're really calling the `apply` **method** of the `Donut` **object**.
When you mark a class as a `case class`, scala will automatically generate a bunch of things for you, between them a *companion object* for your class with an apply method that takes all the arguments you define.
That's why if you define it as just a normal class, the line will fail - you can call `new Donut("Glazed Donut", "Very Tasty")` instead. Or you could create the apply method by hand.

```
class Donut(val name: String, val tasteLevel: String) // vals needed to make the fields public, case classes do this by default.
object Donut {
  /** Factory of Donuts */
  def apply(name: String, tasteLevel: String): Donut = new Donut(name, tasteLevel)
}
```

## Note

[**Case Classes**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) provide another bunch of useful functionalities appart of a simple constructor, like: pretty `toString` implementation, good `hashCode` implementation, *"by value"* comparison, simple *"copying"*, *extractors* for **pattern matching**, *etc* - that remove *"boilerplate"* from the code.
Thus if you need a couple of these features and the class is not intended to be mutated, prefer a **case class** than implementing everything by yourself.

> " Also i want to understand why '(' ')' is printed in my second print statement."

Scala's `print` function, only receives one argument. Thus, what happens when you write `print(a, b)` is that you call print with the tuple `(a, b)` - *(which is the same as calling `print((a, b))`)*.

Comment: Hi so correct me if my understanding  is wrong. when i dont use new keyword to create an instance of an object then  it will be by default we need to use 'case' before class definition ?

Comment: @BalajiKrishnamoorthy not necessarily, This `new C(a, b)` means call a **method**, _(called the constructor)_, from a **class** `C` passing the **arguments** `a` & `b`. Whereas, this `foo(a, b)` means call the `apply` **method** from foo passing the **arguments** `a` & `b`. If foo is an instance of a **class** `C` such class must define that method, but foo could also be an [scala **object**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html), is the object itself the one that must define the **method** - usually the **object** will be a **companion object** from some **class**...

Comment: ... in those cases, usually the `apply` **method** is seen as a factory of instances of the **class**. Making a **class** a **case class** will guarantee the **companion object** and the `apply` **method**, because the Scala compiler itself will generate them. But, nothing stops you from doing the same by hand - I will update the answer to provide an example.