# How the sample Simple IO Type get rid of side effects in "FP in Scala"?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, io-monad

I am reading chapter 13.2.1 and came across the example that can handle IO input and get rid of side effect in the meantime:

```
object IO extends Monad[IO] {
  def unit[A](a: => A): IO[A] = new IO[A] { def run = a }
  def flatMap[A,B](fa: IO[A])(f: A => IO[B]) = fa flatMap f
  def apply[A](a: => A): IO[A] = unit(a)    
}

def ReadLine: IO[String] = IO { readLine }
def PrintLine(msg: String): IO[Unit] = IO { println(msg) }

def converter: IO[Unit] = for {
  _ <- PrintLine("Enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ")
  d <- ReadLine.map(_.toDouble)
  _ <- PrintLine(fahrenheitToCelsius(d).toString)
} yield ()
```

I have couple of questions regarding this piece of code:

1. In the `unit` function, what does `def run = a` really do?
2. In the `ReadLine` function, what does `IO { readLine }` really do? Will it really execute the `println` function or  just return an IO type?
3. What does `_` in the for comprehension mean (`_ <- PrintLine("Enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ")`) ?
4. Why it removes the IO side effects? I saw these functions still interact with inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The definition of your `IO` is as follows:

   ```
   trait IO { def run: Unit }
   ```

   Following that definition, you can understand that writing `new IO[A] { def run = a }` means initialising an anonymous class from your trait, and assigning `a` to be the method that runs when you call `IO.run`. Because `a` is a [by name parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html), nothing is actually ran at creation time.
2. Any object or class in Scala which follows a contract of an `apply` method, can be called as: `ClassName(args)`, where the compiler will search for an `apply` method on the object/class and convert it to a `ClassName.apply(args)` call. A more elaborate answer [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/what-is-the-apply-function-in-scala). As such, because the `IO` companion object posses such a method:

   ```
   def apply[A](a: => A): IO[A] = unit(a)
   ```

   The expansion is allowed to happen. Thus we actually call `IO.apply(readLine)` instead.
3. `_` [has many overloaded uses in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala). This occurrence means "I don't care about the value returned from `PrintLine`, discard it". It is so because the value returned is of [type Unit](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/Unit.html), which we have nothing to do with.
4. It is not that the `IO` datatype *removes* the part of doing IO, it's that it *defers* it to a later point in time. We usually say IO runs at the "edges" of the application, in the `Main` method. These interactions with the out side world will still occur, but since we encapsulate them inside IO, we can reason about them **as values** in our program, which brings a lot of benefit. For example, we can now *compose* side effects and depend on the success/failure of their execution. We can mock out these IO effects ([using other data types such as `Const`](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Const.html)), and many other surprisingly nice properties.

Comment: Hi @Yuval Thanks so much! BTW, can I know which function would be assigned to `a` within IO? And how we'll invoke the `IO.run`?

Comment: @injoy `a` will be whichever function you supply. For example, one of your expressions is `IO { readLine }`, where we assign the read lines function as `a`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the three lines inside the for comprehension all return IO types. They not really print lines to stdout, right? So how can we really print those lines? thanks.

Comment: @injoy After you get back the `IO[Unit]` value from the `converter` method, you need to call `run`: `converter.run`. Note again that running the IO should happen at the edges of your program.

Comment: Hi @Yuval, how the for comprehension return the IO[Unit] value? I thought the `_ <- PrintLine(fahrenheitToCelsius(d).toString)` will discard the IO value, right? Also, what does the `yield ()` do? Thanks.

Comment: @injoy It will not discard IO, it will discard the `Unit` value returned inside IO. `yield ()` will yield the unit value.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to look at `IO` monad as a small piece of program definition.

Thus:

1. This is `IO` definition, `run` method defines what `IO` monad does. `new IO[A] { def run = a }` is scala way of creating an instance of class and defining method `run`.
2. There is a bit of syntactical sugar is going on. `IO { readLine }` is same as `IO.apply { readLine }` or `IO.apply(readLine)` where `readLine` is call-by-name function of type `=> String`. This calls the `unit` method from `object IO` and thus this is just creation of instance of `IO` class that does not run yet.
3. Since `IO` is a monad, for comprehension can be used. It requires storing a result of each monad operation in a syntax like `result <- someMonad`. To ignore the result, `_` can be used, thus `_ <- someMonad` reads as execute the monad but ignore the result.
4. This methods are all `IO` definitions, they don't run anything and thus there is no side effect. Side effects only appears when `IO.run` is called.