# Question regarding functional interface in Java8

Tags: java, function, lambda, interface, unary-operator

How does apply() method work in Java?

Regarding the UnaryOperator functional interface, I have read the documentation, it says

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface UnaryOperator<T> extends Function<T,T>
```

Represents an operation on a single operand that produces a result of the same type as its operand. This is a specialization of Function for the case where the operand and result are of the same type.
This is a functional interface whose functional method is `Function.apply(Object)`.

What is the functional method?

I have the following class which implements UnaryOperator interface.

```
    public class Uppercase implements UnaryOperator<String> {
        @Override
        public String apply(String s) {
            return s.trim().toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

In the method call,

```
    new Stream().map(new Uppercase())
```

It converts whatever input stream into uppercase. My question is, does the `apply()` method in Uppercase class get called automatically? ( Is it like the `toString()` method is called automatically by the `println()` method?)

I couldn't find any example without calling `apply()` method explicitly. So please help me understand what happened here.

Comment: Did you use your favorite search engine to look for ***java functional interface*** and read any of the excellent descriptions of how this works?  It is expected that before asking a basic question like this you will have done some research.

Comment: also worth checking the documentation that almost each class/interface commes with: [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) and the Java Language Specification: [JLS §9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It converts whatever input stream into uppercase. My question is, does
> the apply() method in Uppercase class get called automatically?

Indeed that is the role of `Stream.map()` implementation of calling `apply()` on it, therefore you will never do it when `Stream.map()` is invoked.

The abstract class `ReferencePipeline` does that:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public final <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super P_OUT, ? extends R> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    return new StatelessOp<P_OUT, R>(this, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
                                 StreamOpFlag.NOT_SORTED | StreamOpFlag.NOT_DISTINCT) {
        @Override
        Sink<P_OUT> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<R> sink) {
            return new Sink.ChainedReference<P_OUT, R>(sink) {
                @Override
                public void accept(P_OUT u) {
                    downstream.accept(mapper.apply(u)); // <------ HERE 
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

`map()` defined in Stream is declared as :

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

`Stream.map()` expects a `Function` and by passing an `UnaryOperator` you provide all which is required.

> I couldn't find any example without calling apply() method explicitly.
> So please help me understand what happened here.

Generally you don't implement directly the functional interface but you pass a lambda as that is more straight :

```
new Stream().map(s->s.trim().toUpperCase())....
```

Answer (score 4):

> does the apply() method in Uppercase class get called automatically?

The `map` method implemented in `Stream` is responsible for calling the `apply` method of the `Function` that you've created.

*Note*: `Uppercase` implements `UnaryOperator<T>` extends `Function<T, T>` which is where the implementation of `apply` defined by you is called.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's exactly like `toString()` function invokes in `println()` function. `println()` accepts all the object, so by default `toString()` inherits from `java.lang.Object` class as well as `Stream` class's `map()` function accepts `java.util.function.Function` type objects which you exactly done implementing it with `Uppercase` class.

When it comes functional interfaces, functional interface is not just a interface which decorated with `@FunctionalInterface` annotation. Functional interface only could have one instance method. Could have many `static` and `default` methods though. These interfaces basically introduced to work with Java 8's new syntax type called **[Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)**. Otherwise this is just an interface.

Your solution implements like this if you want, creating a anonymous inner class;

```
new Stream().map(new Function() {

    @Override
    public String apply(String s) {
        return s.trim().toUpperCase();
    }
});
```

No need to declare a separate concrete class like `Uppercase`. With the lambda expression, you can shorten the code like this;

```
new Stream().map(s -> s.trim().toUpperCase());
```

This is the usage of functional interfaces' functional methods. This is only possible, when there is only one **instance method**. No need to implement separate class like you did.

Answer (score 0):

> In computer science, Apply is a function that applies functions to arguments.

This might be new to Java, but it's common in functional programming. 
The object can be treated as a function that has apply method to it. So when a new object is created, the apply method will be executed with the passed arguments.

The answer by Vlad Gudim has detailed expalined : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738862/3812323

It's for the scala, but the holds true in functional paradigm.