# Auxiliary Constructor in Scala with multiple parameters

Tags: java, scala

I have a class that is initialized with an integer and a set. I want to create an auxiliary constructor that takes an integer and multiple parameters. These multiple parameters should be the contents of the set.

I need help calling the primary constructor with suitable arguments.

```
final class Soccer[A](max: Int, collection_num: Set[A]) {

///Auxiliary Constructor
/// new Soccer(n,A,B,C)` is equivalent to `new Soccer(n,Set(A,B,C))`.
///This constructor requires at least two candidates in order to avoid ambiguities with the
/// primary constructor.

def this(max: Int, first: A, second: A, other: A*) = {
///I need help calling the primary constructor with suitable arguments.
}

}
```

new Soccer(n,A,B,C)`should be equivalent to`new Soccer(n,Set(A,B,C))

Comment: Why have first and second at all? Just use `elements: A*`.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining [factory apply method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738395/5205022) on the companion object instead of auxiliary constructor like so

```
object Soccer {
  def apply[A](max: Int, first: A, second: A, other: A*): Soccer[A] = {
    new Soccer(max, Set[A](first, second) ++ other.toSet)
  }
}
```

Now construct `Soccer` like so

```
Soccer(n,A,B,C)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the apply method in companion object is a good way to achieve the requirement, but if you really want to do it in auxiliary constructor, you just call the `this` method like:

```scala
final class Soccer[A](max: Int, collection_num: Set[A]) {
  def this(max: Int, first: A, second: A, other: A*) = {
    this(max, Set[A](first, second) ++ other.toSet)
  }
}
```