# Scala - operator definition

Tags: scala, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Scala's apply() method magic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223834/how-does-scalas-apply-method-magic-work)

I am an absolute beginner in Scala and after reading in one of the Scala books that apply function is like "overloaded () operator" I began to wonder how tha is defined. Namely an operator () would take the argument between the brackets themselves, rather than in the conventional infix a () b notation. Is definition of such operator possible in Scala and if so, what is the definition syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already stated in your question, you simply define it by defining a method (*not* a function) called `apply`.

```
foo(bar, baz)
```

gets translated to

```
foo.apply(bar, baz)
```

So, as long as `foo` has an `apply` method of correct arity and type, this will work.

Some examples of implementations of the `apply` method are the `Array` companion object, which allows you to construct an array by calling `Array(1, 2, 3)` (which is actually just `Array.apply(1, 2, 3)`) and the `Array` class, which allows you to access an array element by calling `anArray(i)` (which is actually just `anArray.apply(i)`).

This is similar to e.g. Python, where function calls get translated into calls to the `__call__` operator or Ruby, where an expression of the form `foo.(bar, baz)` gets translated to `foo.call(bar, baz)`.

A similar method is `update`:

```
foo(bar) = baz
```

gets translated to

```
foo.update(bar, baz)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I define an operator '/?'

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was can i define operator /? That will work as a / b ?, similarly to ()?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. And, BTW, it would have taken you less time to try it out yourself than to ask the question.