# Scala factory ignored by compiler?

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar, companion-object

I spent all this time putting together a factory method in my companion object like so:

```
class Stuff(val a: Int, val b: Long) { this() = this(0,0L) }

object Stuff {
  def apply(a:Int, b:Int) = new Stuff(a, b.toLong)
}
```

But when just when I thought I was killing it I then went to compile and this didn't work:

```
val widget = new Stuff(1,2)
```

What is going on!? I just made this!? Help!!!

Comment: Actually, if you correctly insert the missing `def` into the `class`, `new Stuff(1, 2)` should definitely work (as should `new Stuff(1, 2L)`).

Comment: make ctor of Stuff private with `class Stuff private(...) {...}` and no confusion any more.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that classes could also have `apply()` factories as well. Was this added later after the companion object factories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well young Scala coder, have no fear because the answer is simple. You are not using the factory correctly. See, this code will actually do what you want:

```
val widget = Stuff(1,2)
//makes Stuff(1, 2L)
```

The issue here is your syntax. When you call `new` it instantiates a new class of `Stuff`. But `apply` is really syntactic sugar for `widget.apply(1,2)` and there's not much else to it.

You can also learn more about the `apply` sugar here: [How does Scala's apply() method magic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223834/how-does-scalas-apply-method-magic-work)

Keep coding young one.