# Ok helper in play.api.mvc.Results

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an interrogation about the `Ok` helper in `play.api.mvc.Results`.

When I do a:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok("Hello world!")
}
```

in a Play! controller, I am supposed to end up with a `Result` somehow. **Am I not**?

But all I can see in the api documentation is a `val Ok: Status`. My question is **how can scala  end up with a Result with an expression such as `Ok("Hello world")`**?

Is there some `apply` called on Status somewhere? If no how is the Result returned from a simple `val`??

Comment: My question relates to the playframework api/implementation first and the link you provide does not really answer my question... Why is my question considered for closing??

Comment: From the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1223913/406435): `it's just syntactic sugar whereby the compiler converts f(a) into f.apply(a) as a special syntax case`. In you case `Ok("Hello world!")` means `Ok.apply("Hello world!")`.

Comment: Then you confirm that Ok is of type Status?

Comment: Yes, since `def index` is part of some `class`/`object` that extends `Controller` it should be a field `Ok` of `Controller`. And yes, it has type `Status` with `apply` method.