# Creating Objects from type alias in Scala

Tags: scala, typedef

How can one construct an object from a type alias in scala?

```
type MyType = List[Int]
println(List[Int]())
println(MyType())  // error: not found: value MyType
```

This is problematic in a function that must return a new instance of that type.  Basic Example:

```
def foo(x: MyType): MyType = {
  if (x.head == 0) MyType() // Should Nil be used?
  else if (x.head == -1) new MyType(1,2,3,4)
  else x
}
```

How can `foo` become unaware of the actual type of `MyType`?

Comment: you do realize that my answer gives you what you asked for whereas the answer you selected does not... right?

Comment: Yes your answer provides the explicit results requested, but it offers little explanation how it is achieved and why it is necessary.  Your answer also offers no explanation as why the expected solution was not possible, where the selected answer does.  Perhaps I phrased my question inappropriately; _why_ in this case is more pertinent than _how_.

Comment: It's too bad that _why_ didn't show up in your question or else it could've been answered. Even the selected answer doesn't describe the pattern of type vs. companion object. </rant>

Comment: If you believe you can provide more insight than the selected question then please do.

Comment: Insight has been generated (see below). I hope you've been enjoying learning Scala; it's absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scala (like Java) has different namespaces for types and values, and a type alias only introduces the alias into the type namespace. In some cases you can pair the alias with a `val` referring to the companion object to get the effect you're looking for:

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> type MyType = Foo
defined type alias MyType

scala> val MyType = Foo
MyType: Foo.type = Foo

scala> MyType(1)
res0: Foo = Foo(1)
```

This won't work with `List[Int]`, though, since while both the `List` type and the `List` companion object's `apply` method have a type parameter, the `List` companion object itself doesn't.

Your best bet is to use something like `Nil: MyType`, but you'll find that in general using type aliases like this (i.e. just as a kind of abbreviation) often isn't the best solution.

Comment: What's wrong with `val MyType = List`? Then `MyType[Int]()` will desugar to `MyType.apply[Int]()` and everyone is happy...

Comment: @gzm0: Having `MyList` be both generic (for the term) and specific to `Int` (for the type) seems like a recipe for confusion to me.

Comment: Oh, yes indeed. I saw that wrong... Thought the alias is higher-kinded. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me you're trying to achieve something with the wrong set of tools. But in any case there is no way to instantiate a type alias.

Is your goal to make the function work on a set of different collection types as opposed to only Lists? In that case you need more than just nominal decoupling; currently the function still relies on the method signatures of List.

You can decouple your function from the interface of `List` by using type classes, but you'll have to wrap every method call you'll ever want to make in `MyOps`:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait MyOps[L[_], T] {
  def head(xs: L[T]): T
  def tail(xs: L[T]): L[T]
  def fromList(xs: List[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): L[T]
}

implicit def listMyOps[T] = new MyOps[List, T] {
  def head(xs: List[T]) = xs.head
  def tail(xs: List[T]) = xs.tail
  def fromList(xs: List[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = xs
}

implicit def arrayMyOps[T] = new MyOps[Array, T] {
  def head(xs: Array[T]) = xs(0)
  def tail(xs: Array[T]) = xs.slice(1, xs.size)
  def fromList(xs: List[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = xs.toArray
}

def foo[L[_]](xs: L[Int])(implicit ev: MyOps[L, Int]) = {
  ev.fromList(xs = if (ev.head(xs) == -1) List(1, 2, 3) else Nil)
}

println(foo(List(0, 1, 2, 6)))
println(foo(Array(-1, 6, 8)))
```

outputs:

```
List()
[I@54b63af0
```

— the first `foo` call takes a `List` and returns a `List`; the 2nd one `Array` and `Array` respectively.

Comment: The goal is clearly abstraction and identification.  Users of MyType need not know it is a List[Int] and one can differentiate a MyType from any other random List[Int]

Comment: So you want to be able to swap out the backing type of `MyType` for something other than `List`? (wait, nvm; I thought you were the asker)

Comment: Yes that is the idea.  I want functions using `MyType` to be abstracted from the actual type.

Comment: OK, so start by describing the values the functions need to deal with — then I'll show you how to create a type class that maps real values to your abstract values.

Answer (score 1):

A type is just a type, not any information about how to create instances of that.

You would have to provide it with a function that constructs an instance of the alias.

So for example

```
def foo(x: MyType)(create: List[Int] => MyType) =
  if (x.head == 0) create(Nil) // Should Nil be used?
  else if (x.head == -1) create(List(1,2,3,4))
  else x
```

But as Erik says, it sounds like you are doing something a bit backwards.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of Scala Collections for every collection type there exists a companion object that helps make it easier to construct instances of the collection.

For simplicity consider this class and object of the same name:

```
object Numeric {
  def apply(s: String): Numeric = new Numeric(s.toDouble)
}

case class Numeric(v: Double)
```

If you only had the case class then writing `Numeric("5.1")` would be erroneous. With the object you can actually now call `Numeric.apply("5.1")` or (because `apply` is a [special method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223834/how-does-scalas-apply-method-magic-work)) you can simply write `Numeric("5.1")`. `object` in Scala is analogous to holding all `static` methods that you would write in Java.

Back to your example, `MyType` is only the type alias to `List[Int]` and does not bring the `List` companion object into scope with the name `MyType`. Your example is the equivalent of my `Numeric` example without the companion object.

Thus, my answer, is to create a simple and generic way to construct your companion object that hides the fact that 1) `MyType` is an alias and 2) that it restricts the collection type to `Int`. If you have lots of type aliases like this one in your code then you'll probably want the more generic version here:

```
import scala.collection.GenTraversable
import scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion

class TypeCompanion[CC[X] <: GenTraversable[X], T](companion: GenericCompanion[CC]) {
  type InnerType = CC[T]
  def apply(elems: T*): InnerType = companion.apply(elems: _*)
  def empty(): InnerType = companion.empty[T]
}

object MyType extends TypeCompanion[List, Int](List)
type MyType = MyType.InnerType
```

If you want to reduce the number of times that you write `List`, and will not mind the extra typing if you need to change from `Int` to some other type, then you may prefer this variation:

```
class TypeCompanion[CC[X] <: GenTraversable[X]](companion: GenericCompanion[CC]) {
  type InnerType = CC[Int]
  def apply(elems: Int*): InnerType = companion.apply(elems: _*)
  ...
}

object MyType extends TypeCompanion(List)
type MyType = MyType.InnerType
```

Both implementations give your `foo` method this implementation:

```
def foo(x: MyType): MyType = {
  if (x.head == 0) MyType()
  else if (x.head == -1) MyType(1,2,3,4)
  else x
}
```

Note that the type restrictions on `GenTraversable` and `GenericCompanion` are just a clever way of restricting to companion objects that match scala collection's conventions.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the downvote... But my intention here is to demonstrate how you can define a MyType that is constrained by a GenericCompanion that enables one to construct instances of MyType.

Comment: I simplified my answer greatly. With this example you have the ability to just do: MyType() to obtain what List() would do.

Comment: but what is the point of a this? give an answer that does *exactly* what was asked? because that's hardly useful.