# How can I create and use a type alias with a fixed generic parameter in Scala3?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm trying to define and use a type alias in Scala3 for `scala.collection.immutable.Set[scala.collection.immutable.BitSet]` like so:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{BitSet => Set, Set => SSet}

object Main extends App {
  type Algebra = SSet[Set]

  val omega = Set(1,2,3,4,5,6)
  val empty = Set()
  val A = Algebra(omega, empty) // error: Not found: Algebra
}
```

I think I'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Objects from type alias in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720506/creating-objects-from-type-alias-in-scala)

Comment: thank you! only partially, as I understand the problem now, but the suggested answers don't work in my case

Comment: `Algebra` is a type, not a value. You can't call the `apply` method on a type; because types don't have methods.